# WPF Dynamic Nested Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Suppose I have a view with the following control (DataContext is properly set to a view model that implements INotify):

When the view is first shown, Document is non existant (null). During runtime (after the user opens a Document), then Document and dependent structure (including Document.SelectedFrame.Image) is created.

At that point, I do invoke the PropertyChaned handler of my SelectedFrame object (which also implements INotifyProperty), but nothing happens.

Do I have to re-tie the bindings at runtime when Document gets created?

Comment: If you say everything is done right, but it doesn't work, it is hard to help. Please post the pertinent code/XAML.

Comment: I didn't say everything is done right did I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a binding which looks something like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Document.SelectedFrame.Image}"></Image>
```

You need to raise PropertyChanged on the ViewModel class when the value of Document changes.  It should look something like this:

```
public object Document
{
    get { return document; }
    set
    {
        document = value;
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Document"));
    }
}
```